# Since when it is possible to open multiple DE/WM in different consoles?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, history, virtual-consoles

I remember some time ago I couldn't start X in two consoles at the same time. What I mean, if I had i3 running on tty7, I could do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to go to tty6, I could log in, but I couldn't start another, say i3 session.

Recently I've noticed it's possible.

When did this change occur?

Comment: Do you remember why you couldn’t? I’ve been running multiple X servers in different VTs since the 90s...

Comment: @StephenKitt, the simple fact that you ask that... makes me wonder whether I was just doing some wrong attempt :/ But part of me also remembers reading something somewhere about "you can't do this with X, you need Wayland".

Comment: I wonder what the context of that quote was — perhaps the person writing it had some specific scenario in mind (or perhaps they were mistaken). GNOME for example has had support for desktop switching (multiple X sessions in parallel) for a long time, and the X server itself supports VT switching and VT selection on Linux since forever. I used to run a 16-bit colour X server in the 90s, but that wouldn’t work with some games so I had to use an 8-bit colour X server on another VT for those.

Comment: yeah, having a dungeon crawler / round-based RPG DnD-rules-following game on my first X server and Mozilla (and later Seamonkey) showing a monster manual on the second X server is definitely something I did two decades ago. So, I honestly think there was no time where Arch existed (2002 onwards) and when that could have been impossible on Linux. Thus, I don't think there's really a question here!